# RabbitVCS /w Subversion 1.7 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking, nautilus, svn

I have a trouble with RabbitVCS on Ubuntu 14.04 and SVN 1.7.
I compiled **Subversion 1.7.10**, afterwards installed RabbitVCS via following command:

```
python setup.py install --install-layout=deb
```

Then I added python script to nautilus as described in README to the folder:

```
/usr/share/nautilus-python/extensions
```

The subversion on its own is working well (tested pre RabbitVCS installation). But the context menu in nautilus is not offering desired commands.

The repositories I am working with are placed in the network, which I connected to on startup via **/etc/fstab** and **sshfs** like so:

```
sshfs#myuser@12.34.56.78:/remote/folder /media/mymount fuse  delay_connect,follow_symlinks,idmap=user,allow_other,_netdev,workaround=rename  0  0
```

Network drive is mounted by root but it is accessible by my user, yet I am not sure if subversion requires some extra privileges for acccess.

I am not sure if there should be some extra configuration for the SVN part (since my credentials to SVN differ from the ones I have to the network).

All in all **RabbitVCS nautilus3 extension** looks like it doesn't recognize the repository and it doesn't offer the right actions for the working directory.